# Binding datagridview font color in datatable c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

So right now I have set up datatable and binded it to datagridview.

What my program does is that it saves realtime log to the datatable. 
However I need it to have a font color in each row based on the log level so I save its font color at each row in data table (6th array of datatable)

Is there a solution to bind style to a with datatable and datagridview?

I am also using filter to search as well so I need to be able to backup to the color that it once had before the color was implented.

currently this is what i am doing. Biggest problem to this is that after filter has been implemented, the style property is all gone and it becomes again no colored colum (all black again)

```
if (value.Contains("<Notice>:"))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen;
                    logParserView.Rows[rowNumber][6] = "ForestGreen";
                }
                else if (value.Contains("<Debug>:"))
                {
                   dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                    logParserView.Rows[rowNumber][6] = "Orange";
                }
                else if (value.Contains("<Info>:"))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                    logParserView.Rows[rowNumber][6] = "Orange";
                }
                else if (value.Contains("<Warning>:"))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                    logParserView.Rows[rowNumber][6] = "Orange";
                }
                else if (value.Contains("<Error>:"))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
                    logParserView.Rows[rowNumber][6] = "DarkRed";
                }
                else if (value.Contains("<Critical>:"))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
                    logParserView.Rows[rowNumber][6] = "DarkRed";
                }
                else if (value.Contains("<Alert>:"))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
                    logParserView.Rows[rowNumber][6] = "DarkRed";
                }
                else if (value.Contains("<Emergency>:"))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.IndianRed;
                    logParserView.Rows[rowNumber][6] = "IndianRed";
                }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you simply need to handle the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event, and in the handler, set the `CellStyle` of the `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` handler argument.

Cheers

EDIT:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value == someOtherValue)
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How does cell formatting work when i am using the row filtering? Can this cell formatting be done based on the text each column posssess?

Comment: The `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` contains all the properties required to access the cell that is currently formatting, so yes, you can base your formatting on the cell's value.

Comment: Last question @Luc Morin. If so where would i bind datagridviewcellformatingevent args to? Which event handler should i bind this to?

Comment: I told you, the DataGridView.CellFormatting event

Comment: Is that for Web, or for Windows Forms ?

Comment: this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView_CellFormatting); yes this is what i am trying to do according to your opinion but it spits out no overload for datagridview_cellformatting matches delegate eventhandler error

Comment: This is for native app windows form

Comment: Do you add your event handlers manually ? Use the Windows Forms Designer to add it, then it will have the proper signature: `this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);`

Comment: Thanks Luc Morin. It really helped!

Comment: No problem. If it really helped you, then maybe you can mark my answer ?